# Activation Lock - Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, activation-lock

I have recently sold my Apple Watch on Ebay. Before posting it i went through the following proceedure:

1. Keep your Apple Watch and iPhone close together.
2. Open the Watch app on your iPhone and tap the My Watch tab.
3. Tap Apple Watch, then tap Unpair Apple Watch.
4. Enter your Apple ID password. If you forgot your Apple ID password, you can reset it.
5. Tap again to confirm.

If you can't access your iPhone or Apple Watch, or if your Apple Watch isn't paired with your iPhone and you need to turn off Activation Lock:

1. On a computer, go to iCloud.com.
2. Sign in with your Apple ID, and open Settings.
3. Under My Devices, click your Apple Watch.
4. Click X next to your device.
5. Click Remove to confirm.

The customer has recently emailed me to inform me that he cannot connect and it is still registered to my Apple ID.  I have checked my Devices on the website and I don't have it registered to my account.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to "hard reset" the Apple Watch?

1. Launch the Settings app on your Apple Watch.
2. Tap on General.
3. Tap on Reset.

   [image]
4. Tap on Erase All Content and Settings.
5. Type in your passcode (if required).
6. Tap on Continue to confirm the reset.

   [image]